# What is int a=(i*+3); and how c compiler will execute it?

Tags: c, parsing, operators, expression

HERE IS THE CODE

```
int i = 3
int a=(i*+3);
```

---

NOT UNDERSTAND CODE IS

```
a=(i*+3)
```

value of a = 9

---

Comment: It should be easier to understand if we separate the sub-expressions a little: `int a = i * +3`. Which is equivalent to `int a = i * (+3)`. Which of course is `int a = i * 3`.

Comment: ```a = i * (+3)``` The ```+``` is a useless unary operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context of usage in `C` is needed to understand several multi-use symbols, such as the `+` symbol, which by itself has at least 3 uses found commonly in `C` expressions:

- addition operator  ( eg `int a = 3 + 5;` )
- sign indicating a positive value ( eg `int a = +3 - (+3);` )
- and when doubled, a value incrementor.   ( `for(int a=0; a<limit; a++)` )

When used with other multi-use symbols, such as `*`, determining whether it is *sign*, *operator* or incrementor is by context of usage.

Typically in this context you would use an implicit `+` sign:

```
int a=(i*3);// i * +3
```

But it is also legal (but not as readable) to use an *explicit* sign.  So by context of usage in this statement...

```
int a=(i*+3);// by context '+' is a sign in this case, not an operator
```

...is simply using an explicit sign for `3`, and the two statements are equivalent.

A more readable version:

```
int a=(i * (+3));
```

Another similar seemingly confusing scenario, but contextually meaningful:

```
int func(int *value){

    int a = 10+*value;//by context '*' is de-referencing 'value' not multiplying
    return a;
}
```

Note: readability could have been improved here by spacing:

```
int a = 10 + *value;  //spacing is good for readability and removing ambiguity
```

Answer (score 3):

It is just a bad code formatting. To make the declaration clear rewrite it like

```
int i = 3;
int a = i * +3;
```

inserting blanks between tokens. Though the unary plus operator is redundant here.

One more confusing expression

```
int a = i+++3;
```

It is the same as

```
int a = i++ + 3;
```

From the C Standard (6.4 Lexical elements)

> 4 If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to
>   a given character, the next preprocessing token is the longest
>   sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token.

You can get many such confusing expressions omitting blanks between tokens.

Though in C there are dark corners that you should know.

For example if you have a function declaration like

```
void f( int x );
```

then it can be called like

```
(**********f)( 10 );
```

that is equivalent to

```
f( 10 );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int x )
{
    printf( "I'm called with %d stars!\n", x );
}

int main(void) 
{
    ( **********f )( 10 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
I'm called with 10 stars!
```

Comment: Oh, I like the [`-->` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c) as well...